# compileOptions set to JavaVersion 1.8 cause gradle to fail sync

Tags: java, android, gradle

I would like to use some java 8 features in my app (namely the usage of a json library)

However, when I add

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

to my `build.gradle` the Gradle project sync failes:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

I am using Android studio on Ubuntu 19.04 with the following Java versions installed

```
wouter@Wouter-Laptop:~/Android/Sdk$ sudo update-alternatives --config java 
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode
wouter@Wouter-Laptop:~/Android/Sdk$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac    1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac to provide /usr/bin/javac (java
```

My `build.gradle` looks like

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        signingConfigs {
        }
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "nl.wouter.cycleweatherapp"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }


    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
        implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.2'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    }
```

Removing the Java 1.8 part in the `build.gradle` file removes the error but gives no java 1.8 features. 
Next to switching and installing java versions I have tried to invalidate and regenerate the gradle cache.

I have no clue how to proceed, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it by installing a Ubuntu LTS in vitrualbox and using that to do the development

Comment: this problem occurs for windows as well so this solution is not universal.